# I want to remove header for particular catagory and I need to add custom header

Tags: magento-1.9, header

I want to remove header for particular catagory and I need to add custom header

```
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="header"/>
</reference>
</reference name="root">
<additem name="/path of header">
</reference>
```

Can i use the above code to remove the header and add new header in particulat catagory

Comment: you use css try :- .category .custom-header {
display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this through the admin control panel in Magento using a custom layout update setting on the category editor:

- Log in to your admin console and visit Catalog > Manage Categories.
- Select the category you want to change in the left column.
- Click the "Custom Design" tab in the middle column.
- Set "Use Parent Category Settings" to "No"
- inside the "Custom Layout Update" box add the following:

`<remove name="header" />`

- Save the category's changes and go check your website.

This will affect the selected category and all it's child categories by default. If you later want to change another category, you can repeat these steps in that category. You can also re-edit this category and reverse these steps to change the design of that category back again.